# Bitwise operations on elements from array of chars

Tags: c++, hex, bit-manipulation

I have made array of hexadecimal numbers that I would like to add together bitwise. In my program I want to add 0xFF with 0x7F00. Here is my approach

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char data[2] = {0xFF, 0x7F};

    cout << (data[0] | (data[1] << 8)) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the result to be 0x7FFF which is 32767 in decimal, but I get -1 (0xFF in hex).

Comment: If your chars are 8 bit, which they most likely are, then `(data[1] << 8)` is undefined behavior. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic): *"The behavior is undefined if rhs is negative or is greater or equal the number of bits in the promoted lhs."*

Comment: It is implementation defined if `char` is signed or unsigned. I recommend you explicitly use `uint8_t` or `int8_t` if you want the array to contain (unsigned or signed) non-character data.

Comment: @Blaze Note the "promoted lhs" part of your quote. For [bitwise shift](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_shift_operators) integral promotion is performed on both operators.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude good to know, thanks. I've read in another answer that there's no promotion for bitshift, but that might have been only for the result, not the operands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having stems from two facts:

1. The [bitwise operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators) requires [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) of both operands.
2. `char` can be either signed or unsigned

Promotion will convert values of smaller types (like `char` or `short`) to `int`, and as part of that signed values will be sign-extended. If `char` is signed, then the value `0xff` will be converted to the (32-bit) `int` value `0xffffffff`, which is `-1`.

It doesn't matter what value you use in the bitwise OR, the result will still be `0xffffffff`.

The simple solution is to explicitly use `unsigned char` (or even better `uint8_t`) as the type for the array elements:

```
uint8_t data[2] = {0xFF, 0x7F};
```

Comment: I think I get the idea behind this. Thank you, it works now.

Comment: @Fareanor Ok. Sorry, I didn't know about this feature.

Comment: @Ikaruga Don't worry, there was no problem :) This feature is useful for other readers that may have encounter the same issue. It makes the answer "more trustworthy" if they see that the OP (original poster) has accepted it.